# manipulate ASCII grid

Tags: r, rgdal

I have an ASCII grid (Data information in this box link https://app.box.com/s/jpdalfjnyfhqbvrghd8csu3pz5b2fl2j) with the following projection information

```
Projection    POLAR
Units         METERS
Zunits        NO
Xshift        0.0
Yshift        0.0
Parameters    6378137.0  6356752.314245179
   0  0  0.0 /* longitude of central meridian
  45  0  0.0 /* latitude of true scale
0.0 /* false easting (meters)
0.0 /* false northing (meters)

 PROJCS["Stereographic_North_Pole", GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
 DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
 PROJECTION["Stereographic_North_Pole"],
 PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",45], PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
 PARAMETER["false_easting",0], PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
 UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

How can I plot it using the projection information correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `LAME-*.asc` *and* a matching `LAME-*.prj` file. If you read the raster using any software that uses the underlying GDAL library it will pick up the projection. In R, for example:

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> r = raster("./LAME_EAU.FRANCE.201303210000.46.5_2.0_45.0_4.2.asc")
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 156, 179, 27924  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent      : 151347.9, 330347.9, -4504818, -4348818  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=45 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : /nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/SO/My Documents/LAME_EAU.FRANCE.201303210000.46.5_2.0_45.0_4.2.asc 
names       : LAME_EAU.FRANCE.201303210000.46.5_2.0_45.0_4.2
```

The coordinate reference has been set. This gives me a raster here:

[image]

If that's in the right place (I don't know) then job done.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am actually a beginner, so I am a bit lost. Would you mind if I share the data with you so you can verify the answer ?

Comment: If you can put the data on a sharing service (box.com, dropbox.com etc) then edit your question and put the link there.

Comment: The doc on [+stere](https://proj4.org/operations/projections/stere.html) is ambiguous. Try changing +lat_0=90.0 and adding +lat_ts=45.0. The statement now is an oblique stereographic, not one centered at the north pole.

Comment: @Spacedman I added the link as you said

Comment: If its meant to be roughly centred on Clermont-Ferrand then I think we're done.